# Copy text between labels (catchfilebetweentags package)

Tags: catchfile

I would like to copy parts of a .tex file into another .tex file AND for these parts to be defined as everything that is between two particular labels.

I've tried the `catchfilebetweentags` package and the `\CatchFileBetweenDelims` macro is getting very close.

However, instead of copying the contents of a file between two delimiters, say `<begin>` and `<end>`, I'd like to copy the contents between two labels `\label{begin}` and `\label{end}`.